# How to check if an array containing strings, has certain words in it from another string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a input string array (called inputArray_1) of length 3. I have another string array (called keywords) with keywords like so:

```
 System.out.println("Input 1:");

 for (int i = 0; i < inputArray_1.length; i++)
 {
     inputArray_1[i] = reader.nextLine();
 }


String[] keywords = {"dog", "cat", "monkey", "apple"};
```

The output of inputArray_1 might look like this:

```
The dog had many friends.
```

So I want to check each index of the array, and see if the string's at each index has any of the keywords in it. It doesn't have to include all the keywords just one of them.

So far I have this and it is not giving me the right input.

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray_1.length; i++)
        {

            if(inputArray_1[i].contains(keywords[i]))
            {
                System.out.println("YAY");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("BOO");

        }
```

Comment: What would "the right input" be, and what do you get instead?  Can you show *any* effort at trying to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: You need a nested loop. Currently you are checking if `inputArray[i]` contains `keyword[i]` - so you'll only check whether the first one contains 'dog' or the second contains 'cat', etc. You need another loop inside the first one that iterates over every `keywords`.

Answer (score 1):

Along with everyones solution, If you want to test some java 8 *Stream* and *lambda* following is the way you can do it easily

```
 String[] keywords = {"dog", "cat", "monkey", "apple"};

 Arrays.stream(inputArray_1).forEach(
            input -> {
                if (Arrays.stream(keywords).anyMatch(input::equals)) {
                    System.out.println("YAY");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("BOO");
                }
            });
```

- First you are taking Stream of your `inputArray_1` and iterating it using `forEach`
- Then each of your input is matched against the `keywords` array. `anyMatch` here gives you the boolean value `true` if it exists and `false` if it not. You are the simply using that logic to print your outputs

If you feel interest about this cool **Java 8** stuff. Dig this [Java 8 Stream Tutorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) for better understanding how the **Stream API** and **Lambda** works. And also this specific tutorial to [Check if Array contains a certain value](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-check-if-array-contains-a-certain-value/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that inputArray_1 is a String array that results from splitting on white spaces, you would need some type of inner loop that checks the current String from the input array, against all Strings from the keywords array. So something like:

```
        String [] inputArray_1 = new String [] {"word3","word2","word3"};
    String [] keywords = new String [] {"word1","word3"};

    outerloop:
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray_1.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
            if(inputArray_1[i].equals(keywords[j])){
                System.out.println("YAY");
                continue outerloop;
            }               
        }

        System.out.println("BOO");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use another loop for the keywords inside the 1st loop to check every elements in the keywords list.

Answer (score 0):

If the `inputArray_1` contains sentences(strings with whitespace and > 1 words), you would want to iterate through each keyword to check if the current sentence, or `inputArray_1[i]`, `.contains()` that keyword.

But if your `inputArray_1`just contains values of single words/no sentences, then you could just have one loop like so.

```
//This will only work if inputArray_1 contains no sentences, just single words
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray_1 .length; i++)
    {
        if(keywords.contains(inputArray_1[i]))
        {
            System.out.println("YAY");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("BOO");
        }

    }
```